# How can you get Firebug to show the script window and the console simultaneously

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'd like to be able to execute code in the console at the same time as viewing the script I'm debugging but I can only seem to get one or the other. Is there a way to see both simultaneously?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just Enable `Show Command Line` option or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - unfortunately I can't find where that option is located though (Firefox on OSX)

Comment: Ahh - great, thanks for the shot. I had no idea that was even a button!

Comment: Don't worry - I was going to. I actually tried twice but I was too early each time

Comment: Is there any way to also clear console when **not** in Console panel? (E.g. in HTML or Script panel?)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. What I meant: is there a way to do it from the Console user interface (some button, some context menu item), _not_ from the command line. Thx

Comment: @superjos: AFAIK, no. But then, I'm not sure about GUI options. I've moved to Chrome Dev Tools and rarely use Firebug now. Maybe there is a way to get Firebug listen to a key shortcut by modifying its plugin manifest (or something similar). I would suggest asking this in Firebug forums.